# How to extract soap response inside the body tag in soapUI Groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have response like this .

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns3:ResponseElement xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/services/common/example/xsd" xmlns:ns3="http://www.example.com/example/xsd">
         <Info>
            <Data>
               <Site>OneValue</Site>
            </Data>
            <OtherData>
               <Code>56789</Code>
               <Time>2017-07-30</Time>
               <SecondCode>ThirdValue</SecondCode>
               <Number>111</Number>
            </OtherData>
         </Info>
      </ns3:ResponseElement>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

In groovy, how can I extract the response as XML inside the `<S:Body>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

I figured the Answer. It may help other if looking for this

```
def body = context.expand('${TestStepName#Response#//soap:Body}')
log.info body
```